# Is there fall damage? Or only when doing clearly dangerous things like jumping down elevator shafts?

Tags: control

Is there fall damage? Or only when doing clearly dangerous things like jumping down elevator shafts? In which case is immediate death?

Because I notice there's the damage direction indicator when I jump down a bit too high, but I don't track my HP carefully enough to notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is fall damage

The higher the height you are falling from, the bigger the damage. Once you learn how to "evade" or levitate, you can negate the damage by pressing the evade/levitate button before hitting the floor.